# Symfony mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle sums

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, aggregation-framework

For start, I have to say I am new to mongo (3.2). I am using [mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/solution/mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle) for php framework Symfony (2.8.4). I want to get sums of some fields restricted by dates. 
So far, I managed to get sums for all records:

```
$expr = new \Solution\MongoAggregation\Pipeline\Operators\Expr;
        $aq = $this->manager->getCollection('AppBundle:UserDaySums')->createAggregateQuery()->group([
                            '_id' => 'client.$id',
                            'total' => $expr->sum('$aSum'),
                        ])
```

Now, I'd like to restrict this query by dateFrom,dateTo and userId. I am not sure, how to do it. I know, I should probably use match function, but I don't know how. Or is there some better solution?

Thanks for replies!

KP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the match function. For example, the following assumes you have the date variables for use in the query:

```
$expr = new \Solution\MongoAggregation\Pipeline\Operators\Expr;
$aq = $this->manager->getCollection('AppBundle:UserDaySums')->createAggregateQuery();
$dateFrom = new MongoDate(strtotime('-2 days'));
$dateTo = new MongoDate();
$userId = 'Xsgy62js0lb';

$result = $aq->match(['dateFrom'=>$dateFrom, 'dateTo'=>$dateTo, 'userId'=>$userId ])
             ->group(['_id'=>'client.$id', 'total'=>$expr->sum('$aSum') ])
             ->getQuery()->aggregate();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed. I just modified it to `$aq
                ->match([
                    'date' => $expr->gte($dateFrom),
                    'date' => $expr->lte($dateTo),
                    'user.$id' => $expr->in($userMongoIds)
                ])`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, match() was somewhat tricky on a MongoId object.

This didn't work for me:

```
$userMongoId = "57321c7a2977f8de306ef648";
$aq ->match([ 'user.$id' => $expr->eq($userMongoId) ])
```

This worked:

```
$aq ->match([ 'user' => new \MongoId($userMongoId) ])
```

Tested on Symfony 3 with the SolutionMongoAggregationBundle, MongoDB version 3.2.6.